# Deprecating a method, and linking to a class in a different library

Tags: java

I want to deprecate a method because I want to use a method from a different class in a different library (jar) that provides more standardization.

What I'd like to write is something like this:

```
class MyClass {

/**
 * @deprecated use {@link com.othercompany.theirmodule.TheirClass.bar() }
 */
@Deprecated
void foo() {
...
}
```

However the class `TheirClass` belongs to another jar altogether. Must I add a dependency on their module just for the link in the javadoc 'deprecated' tag?

Comment: No, you don't **need** to add this dependency to your project. You *can* add a dependency and use `TheirClass` as an implementation for your now deprecated method, assuming both work the same. You can also add a hyperlink to some documentation of library that is supposed to replace yours, or simply mention the full library identifier, their verion (in up-from form) and class name, your users can work out required steps themselves.

Comment: Thanks. So I just add a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@link` is a [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) tag. It is used to generate documentation from source code with `javadoc` utility. It is also used by modern IDEs, e.g. `Ctrl+Q` in IntelliJ IDEA to display documentation about class/method under cursor.

But this is just a comment. IDE may highlight it with red if `ThierClass` is not visible or does not have such method, but this is not an error for a compiler.